# Problem to create a new columns in dataframe with lag

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I have a simple data_frame like under :

> Blockquote

```
             timestamp   H_crops H_Tower
1     2021-01-01 00:00:00 0.1000000     2.1
2     2021-01-01 00:30:00 0.1000076      NA
3     2021-01-01 01:00:00 0.1000152      NA
4     2021-01-01 01:30:00 0.1000227      NA
5     2021-01-01 02:00:00 0.1000303      3
6     2021-01-01 02:30:00 0.1000379      NA
7     2021-01-01 03:00:00 0.1000455      NA
8     2021-01-01 03:30:00 0.1000530      NA
9     2021-01-01 04:00:00 0.1000606      10
10    2021-01-01 04:30:00 0.1000682      NA
```

> `Blockquote`

I would like to get the following result :

```
                  timestamp   H_crops H_Tower diff
```

> ```
> 1     2021-01-01 00:00:00 0.1000000     2.1  2.1
> 2     2021-01-01 00:30:00 0.1000076      NA  2.1
> 3     2021-01-01 01:00:00 0.1000152      NA  2.1
> 4     2021-01-01 01:30:00 0.1000227      NA  2.1
> 5     2021-01-01 02:00:00 0.1000303       3   3
> 6     2021-01-01 02:30:00 0.1000379      NA   3
> 7     2021-01-01 03:00:00 0.1000455      NA   3
> 8     2021-01-01 03:30:00 0.1000530      NA   3
> 9     2021-01-01 04:00:00 0.1000606      10   10
> 10    2021-01-01 04:30:00 0.1000682      NA   10
> ```

I try this with dplyr:

```
group_by(timestamp)
  arrange(timestamp)
    mutate(data_glob3, diff= ifelse ( is.na(data_glob3[,"H_Tower"]),lag(H_Tower),data_glob3[,"H_Tower"]))
```

But the result is not good. it should use lag of diff but it is impossible .
Could you help mes please ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Try tidyr::fill()

Answer (score 0):

It is not super clear what you are trying to do with the `group_by` and `arrange` functions there.

I am concretizing @Karthik S's suggestion since you are a newcomer and might not know how to apply it.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydat<- 
  read_table2(
  "timestamp H_crops H_Tower
2021-01-01 0.1000000     2.1
2021-01-01 0.1000076      NA
2021-01-01 0.1000152      NA
2021-01-01 0.1000227      NA
2021-01-01 0.1000303      3
2021-01-01 0.1000379      NA
2021-01-01 0.1000455      NA
2021-01-01 0.1000530      NA
2021-01-01 0.1000606      10
2021-01-01 0.1000682      NA
2021-01-01 0.1000530      NA
2021-01-02 0.1000606      NA
2021-01-02 0.1000682      3
2021-01-02 0.1000682      NA")


mydat %>% 
  group_by(timestamp) %>% 
  fill(H_Tower, .direction = "downup")

#> # A tibble: 14 × 3
#> # Groups:   timestamp [2]
#>    timestamp  H_crops H_Tower
#>    <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 2021-01-01   0.1       2.1
#>  2 2021-01-01   0.100     2.1
#>  3 2021-01-01   0.100     2.1
#>  4 2021-01-01   0.100     2.1
#>  5 2021-01-01   0.100     3  
#>  6 2021-01-01   0.100     3  
#>  7 2021-01-01   0.100     3  
#>  8 2021-01-01   0.100     3  
#>  9 2021-01-01   0.100    10  
#> 10 2021-01-01   0.100    10  
#> 11 2021-01-01   0.100    10  
#> 12 2021-01-02   0.100     3  
#> 13 2021-01-02   0.100     3  
#> 14 2021-01-02   0.100     3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>